Is Toroidal Fourier transform an isomorphism between $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{T}^n)$ and $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{Z}^n)$?
I have a doubt: Is Toroidal Fourier transform an isomorphism between $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{T}^n)$ and $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{Z}^n)$?
Reference: M. Ruzhansky, and V. Turunen, Pseudo-Differential Operators and Symmetries: Background Analysis and Advanced Topics, 1st ed (Birkhaeuser, Basel ; Boston, 2010),

What are $\mathcal D'$ and $\mathcal S'$?

$\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{T}^n)$: periodic distribution space
$\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{Z}^n)$: tempered distribution on integers
